# How to calculate mean reversion values for Hull White tree calibration on MATLAB?

Tags: programming, mean-reversion, hullwhite

As part of a time series analysis, I'm writing a MATLAB program to create a Hull White tree, for the purpose of pricing a coupon-bearing bond.

While using the function **hwvolspec** (volatility specifications), there are six input arguments, two of which are **Alphacurve**, which is the vector of mean reversion values, and **AlphaDates**, which is the vector of mean reversion end dates.

However, the only time series data that I have are the volatility term structures, the zero curves, the market prices of the bond in question, and I also have all the associated dates.

My main question is, how do I figure out the mean reversion values and dates from the data that I have? From where do I get the value of **Alphacurve** and **AlphaDates**? Do I need any additional data?

Comment: Nothing wrong with MATLAB questions